# Troubles appending options to select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some `<select>` that needs to be populated with dynamic values, coming from an array.  My code is pretty simple, the HTML is made by just some empty HTML `<select>` with the same class (`.js-select`).

The JS is quite simple:

```
var $select = $(".js-select");
var ioSensors = [1,2,3]; // The data I want to display in the select
var $optionTpl = $("<option></option>");

for( i=0 ; i<ioSensors.length ; i++ ){
  //also show a leading "None" option
  if(i === 0){ 
    $optionTpl.attr('value','').text('None').appendTo($select);
  }

  $optionTpl.attr('value', ioSensors[i]-1).text(ioSensors[i]).appendTo($select);
}
```

With this code I'm having all my `<select>` correctly updated, but the last one is populated only with the last value of the Array, not showing even the "None" option.

Can anyone help me understand where the problem is and why is it behaving like that? Thanks!

I've made a pen [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzgBzQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already suggested, the reason it doesn't work is because you create a single element and keep moving it around. Move the creation of the element inside the loop, for example as follows:

```
var $select = $(".js-select");
var ioSensors = [1,2,3]; // The data I want to display in the select

for( i=0 ; i<ioSensors.length ; i++ ){
  //also show a leading "None" option
  if(i === 0){ 
    $("<option></option>").attr('value','').text('None').appendTo($select);
  }

  $("<option></option>").attr('value', ioSensors[i]-1).text(ioSensors[i]).appendTo($select);
}
```

If you're wondering why your code seem to work for all the `<select>`s beside the last, according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) when the target of an append is more than one element, jquery will clone the element for the first N-1 targets, and just move the element for the last:

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single
> location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the
> target (not cloned):
>
> ...
>
> **Important**: If there is more than one target element, however,
> cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each
> target except for the last one.

Answer (score 4):

`var $optionTpl = $("<option></option>");` creates an element once, then inside the loop you just keep moving that same element and just giving it a new value.

Create multiple elements inside the loop instead

```
var $select = $(".js-select");
var ioSensors = [1,2,3];

for( var i = 0; i < ioSensors.length; i++ ){

    var $optionTpl = $("<option></option>");

    if(i === 0){ 
        $optionTpl.val('').text('None').appendTo($select);
    } 

    $optionTpl.val(ioSensors[i]-1).text(ioSensors[i]).appendTo($select);

}
```

Comment: You forget that he needs the item None with the item 1 (index 0).

Comment: Doesn't `appendTo` create a clone of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the element to have multiple elements

```js
var $select = $(".js-select");
var ioSensors = [1, 2, 3]; // The data I want to display in the select
var $optionTpl = $("<option></option>");

for (i = 0; i < ioSensors.length; i++) {
  //also show a leading "None" option
  if (i === 0) {
    $optionTpl.clone().val('').text('None').appendTo($select);
  }

  $optionTpl.clone().val(ioSensors[i] - 1).text(ioSensors[i]).appendTo($select);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select"></select>
```

---

You can also write the same like

```js
var $select = $(".js-select");
var ioSensors = [1, 2, 3]; // The data I want to display in the select
var $optionTpl = $("<option></option>");

$("<option />", {
  value: '',
  text: 'None'
}).appendTo($select);
ioSensors.forEach(function(item) {
  $("<option />", {
    value: item - 1,
    text: item
  }).appendTo($select);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-select"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution ([pen of the solution](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpwxWO)):

```
var ioSensors = [1,2,3];

$(".js-select").each(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<ioSensors.length;i++) {
    if(i === 0){
      $("<option value=\"\">None</option>").appendTo($(this));
    }
    $("<option value=\"" + ioSensors[i] + "\">" + ioSensors[i] + "</option>").appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```